# Tooth decay treatments

Tags: dentistry, treatment

I had issues with acid reflux **GERD** and that plus grinding my teeth together when sleeping caused a lot of tooth decay.

At this stage my teeth are a yellowish color and is very thinner than it is exposed to be.

I am 22 years old and it is making me self conscious about myself.

What options do I have for fixing my teeth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat the acid reflux if you can.  A Heidelberg test can distinguish between hypochlorhydria (or even achlorhydria) and hyperchlorhydria, both of which cause the symptoms of acid reflux.  If you have been taking acid-reducing medication with only partial symptomatic relief, it may actually be the case that you're producing too little hydrochloric acid rather than too much.

Get fitted for an occlusal guard and wear it while you sleep.  This will protect against the damage caused by tooth grinding.

Obviously, the first and most essential step is to stop the cause of damage, but there are also several proposed methods for accelerating tooth regeneration.  There is some evidence, contrary to traditional belief, the the body can repair its own tooth decay to a certain limited extent, but using something like a calcium chloride mouthwash may be of help with the repair process.

Comment: Thank you for you post and welcome to Health SE! Post here generally have links and research to verify content. Adding this would result in you following site guidelines thank you! For more site guidelines and rules see the help center and take the site tour :)